# create a CSV file in ADLS from databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I am creating a CSV file in an ADLS folder.

For example: sample.txt is the file name
instead of a single file, I see sample.txt/..,part-000 files.

My question is is there a method to create sample.txt file instead of a directory in pyspark.
df.write() or df.save() both create folders and multiple files inside that directory.

Using Coalesce(1) I can combine multiple part-000 files into one file. but how to create a single csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately, Spark doesn’t support creating a data file without a folder**

To workaround,

Firstly using `coalesce` or `repartition`, create a single part (partition) file.

```py
df\
.coalesce(1)\
.write\
.format("csv")\
.mode("overwrite")\
.save("mydata")
```

The above example produces an **mydata** directory, a `part-000* file`, and hidden files

However, our data is contained in only one CSV file. The name of this file is not user-friendly. We can rename this file and extract it.

```py
data_location = "/mydata.csv/"

files = dbutils.fs.ls(data_location)
csv_file = [x.path for x in files if x.path.endswith(".csv")][0]
dbutils.fs.mv(csv_file, data_location.rstrip('/') + ".csv")
dbutils.fs.rm(data_location, recurse = True)
```

set up account key and configure the storage account to access. then move file from databricks location to adls. To move file, we use `dbutils.fs.mv`

````
```python
storage_account_name = "Storage account name"
storage_account_access_key = "storage account acesss key"

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",storage_account_access_key)

dbutils.fs.cp('/mydata.csv.csv','abfss://demo12@pratikstorage1.dfs.core.windows.net//mydata1.csv')
````

**My Execution:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]